# Rendering a Navbar React Component in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-rails

I have a simple Rails 5 app with the react-rails gem installed. I want to create a Navbar that will appear at the top of every page in my app. I'm new to React, so normally what I would do is include an erb tag in application.html.erb that would render a layout helper called _navbar.html.erb, and would appear above the yield block. How do I accomplish this same thing using the react-rails gem and a navbar component? Rendering a react component from application.html.erb like this does not seem to be working:

```
<body>
  <div id='app'>
    <%= react_component 'Navbar' %>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body>
```

Maybe it has something to do with `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` in application.html.erb being inside `<head>` and the page not being fully rendered yet. Any help would be appreciated (bonus points for including the react-bootstrap navbar component!) Thanks!

Edit: I can now get something to display, but it's not formatted like a navbar. I'm using the react-bootstrap docs example but no luck yet.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is your `Navbar` Component in your `/components` directory?

Comment: Yes, and my components directory is being included by my application.js and components.js

Comment: Oh, I just saw you forgot the parentheses... try `<%= react_component('Navbar') %>`

Comment: Hmm, I included the parentheses and it didn't change. However, I can now at least get something from my Navbar class to show on the page if I move the `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` to the bottom of `<body>`. The problem now is, I'm trying to use react-bootstrap and it's not formatted at all...